# sorted() unable to sort list of chars

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort a list containing integers as chars. e.g:

```
l = ['1', '10', '11', '12', '16', '17', '2', '24', '26', '27', '28', '30', '32', '34', '35', '36', '43', '45', '47', '49', '50', '6', '9']
print(sorted(l))
```

is returning:

```
['1', '10', '11', '12', '16', '17', '2', '24', '26', '27', '28', '30', '32', '34', '35', '36', '43', '45', '47', '49', '50', '6', '9']
```

why sorted() is acting unusually?

Comment: l.sort(key=int) is awesome

Answer (score 2):

Sorted is acting exactly as it should.

These are strings, not integers, so `sorted` sorts first by the first character, then by the second character.

If we want to sort `['1', '2', '12']`, we get `['1', '12', '2']`:

```
1
12
2
```

`sorted` first sorts by the first column, then by the second column.